# Loading Images from a folder (Using C, OpenCV, VisualStudio 2008)

Tags: c, image, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

I am trying to load images from a folder and I am using C, OpenCV, VC++ 2008 Express Edition. My images are located on the desktop and have different names such as Tom.jpg, Flash.jpeg etc.
I want to load images from this folder in my program and do some experiments on images one at a time at a time and save the results of this experiment in .txt file and the name of the .txt file should be same as that of the .jpeg file. as in the experimental data performed on Tom.jpg should be stored in Tom.txt and Flash.jpg should be stored in Flash.txt etc.

I can do the above procedure(Loading image and storing its data in text file) for one image. i can display 10 images one after one after reading the filenames from a text file which I created manually. But in this case, all the data of different pics gets stored in the same text file and I am unable to distinguish between different sets of data.

can anyone suggest a way to load one image at time from a folder and do the necessary experiments and store the data in a different .txt file and doing the same thing for maybe 1000's of images ?

Comment: FYI you can also use [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[`FindNextFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the contents of a directory, if you just want to process all of the files matching a certain pattern (e.g. `*.jpeg`) instead of having to manually specify them all in a text file.

Comment: Yes, Adam your idea worked fine. I was able to scan my folder for all the images. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have at least created a function for your main processing. If you dont, do. Then, just pass the list of your image as argument to your executable, and use a for loop

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      const char* imageName = argv[i];
      process(imageName);
   }
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks remi for the suggestion. I didnt use list of my images. I used adam's idea for scanning the entire folder for images

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which I eventually used:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx

I made a few modifications. I passed two arguements to it. I chose to save the data for different images in the same excel sheet but this time I am able to distinguish between different sets of data. Image file name comes first followed by its data

argv[1] is the directory where all the images are located
argv[2] is the file extension which I want in my code(in my case its jpg)

//*For scanning the folder for jpeg images*

```
StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[1]);          
StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*."));      
StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, argv[2]);

hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

do           
   {  
    //Loading the file from the folder and doing processing on it                 
    }    
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```